# show only those columns which have data value

Tags: sql

I don't known that it is possible or not but i want to ask a question to you as
suppose i have a table as

**table1**

```
id | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat | sun
1  | 100 | 200 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
2  | 200 |  0  | 300 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

So from given table **result** should be ...

```
id | mon | tue | wed |
1  | 100 | 200 |  0  | 
2  | 200 |  0  | 300 |
```

as shown in table1 different columns of week.

If all values in a column is 0 or null then query should ignore to show that column(as shown in result)

Note: if we run a query as `select * from table1` it shows all columns.

While I don't wants a query like `select id,mon,tue,wed from table1`
because no. of showing columns may change.

Please reply to me.

Thank you....

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Do you want to do this directly in SQL or also use a programming language on top of it. Using a Programming language greatly simplifies this :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like that isn't possible in any SQL dialect I'm aware of.

**Either** you do a `SELECT * FROM ....` and get back all the columns, or you do a `SELECT col1, col2, ...., coln FROM ....` and get back those columns defined.

There is no way in standard SQL to get back just those columns that have values.... you can do check on **rows** (  `.. WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL ...` ) but not on columns.

Functionality like this needs to be implemented in your UI - using whatever language you're using. This is not something the database can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2005/2008, you could use pivot/unpivot/dynamic sql. It is hideous and not something I would like to see in production code:

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[table1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[table1]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mon] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tue]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [wed]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [thu]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [fri]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [sat]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [sun]  [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 70) ON [PRIMARY],
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]([mon],[tue],[wed],[thu],[fri],[sat],[sun])
VALUES(100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1]([mon],[tue],[wed],[thu],[fri],[sat],[sun])
VALUES(200, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0)
GO
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
GO
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders = 
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + cast([date] as varchar) + ']',
    '[' + cast([date] as varchar)+ ']'
  )
    FROM ( 
        SELECT distinct [date]
        FROM table1
        UNPIVOT
        ( qty FOR date IN ([mon],[tue],[wed],[thu],[fri],[sat],[sun])
        ) AS Unp
        WHERE qty != 0
) rtn
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders
DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT [id], [date], [qty]
    FROM table1
    UNPIVOT
    ( qty FOR date IN ([mon],[tue],[wed],[thu],[fri],[sat],[sun])
    ) AS Unp    
) piv
PIVOT
( SUM([qty])
  FOR [date] IN ( ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ' )
) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[table1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[table1]
GO
```